# Why did Amelia Shepherd say "My dad walked all my sisters down the aisle" when her dad died when she was 5?

Tags: greys-anatomy

Amelia Shepherd asks Owen in S13E4 "How old was I when my father died?", Owen responds "5". Which makes sense since her father passed away in a robbery shooting.

But in S12E24 Amelia said before her wedding "My father walked all my sisters down the aisle, I have no one, Derek is dead, my father is dead".

Did I hear wrong? Or was she supposed to mention Derek instead of her father?

Comment: Don't know for sure, but I believe Amelia is the youngest of her family. Her father may well have been alive and her sisters old enough for him to see them wed before he died.

Comment: One of my great great great grandfathers Jacob Demuth (1779-1842)' had a son born in 1804 and a daughter born in 1840 36 years later (different wives).  Obviously some of his daughters might have been married before he died in 1842.  Henry Hurst 1771-1834 was the father of Jacob Demuth's third wife who married Jacob in 1822.  In 1822 Henry Hurst also married and had children including a son and a daughter.  So Henry Hurst saw the marriage of at least one daughter but died when his youngest daughter was too young to marry.